# Passing a class object into a template function. C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template function defined as follows:

```
template<class T>
string toString(T value) {

     ostringstream ss;

     if (is_same<T, Student>::value) {
         ss << value.getFirst() << ":" << value.getLast() << ":" << value.getId() << ":" << value.getGpa();
         return ss.str();
     }

     else {
         //ss << value;
         return ss.str();
     }
}
```

If i were to call this function like so:

```
int main(){

      Student studentObj;
      toString(studentObj);

}
```

How do i access this classes various members from the toString function?

I have tried (errors commented)

```
value.getId() //Returns int 
//Error C2228 left of '.getId' must have class/struct/union
```

and

```
value<Student>.getId()
//Error C2275 'Student': illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Thanks in advance!

edit: Class definition

```
class Student {
protected:
    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;
    int id;
    float gpa;
public:
    Student();
    Student(std::string, std::string, int, float);
    Student(const Student &);
    std::string getFirst();
    std::string getLast();
    int getId();
    float getGpa();
};
```

Comment: line 2: string toString(T value).
value is just the name of what ever is being passed into the class.

Comment: It's not a type, you can't do that. Remove the `<T>` part, that's just for declaring

Comment: when doing so value.getId() is still returning an error.

Comment: If the code in this post is the same as the code you are compiling, there is still a `<T>` part here: `value<T>.getFirst()`

Comment: How is `Student` defined? I tried a sample [here](http://rextester.com/QKBZV50645)

Comment: what is the problem ? http://cpp.sh/5ncqb it is working

Comment: Once I add `cout<<myToString(10);` it fails.

Comment: Yeah, @Ajay is right. Still not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You cannot do that. With second phase of template code compilation for any non-`Student` type the `if` part will fail to compile. Not that `if` is runtime, not compile time, even though `std::is_same` is compile time. When you call it as `toString(10)` the compiler still has to compile it **fully** for `int`. It won't evaluate runtime `if` statement and eliminate the `if` (true) block - compiler still has to ***compile*** it, and produce object code for it. And hence the error.

You just need to **specialize** it:

```
template<class T>
string toString(T value) 
{
    ostringstream ss;
    /// skipped code
    return ss.str();
}

// SPECIALIZE for 'Student'
template<>
std::string toString(Student s)
{
    // Code here        
}
```

Add `const` and/or `&` if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example!

Comment: That's a case where [overloading should be preferred over specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score 1):

To access the member functions of a class through template function, try calling this way.

```
Student studentobj;
std::string temp = toString<Student>(studentobj); // This will invoke the member functions of student class 



// Code snippet similar to your query
class test
{
public:
    test(){}
    void callme()
    {
        std::cout<<"In callme function"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
void sample(T obj)
{
    std::cout<<"In sample function"<<std::endl;
    obj.callme();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    test obj;
    sample<test>(obj);
    return 0;
}

Output:
In sample function
In callme function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, vasant. But this doesn't solve the problem in hand.